# Qt/QML How to wrap text in Text Element whick is in Listview

Tags: android, qt, qml

I have ListView like :

```
 Rectangle {
            width:(parent.width)
            height: (parent.height/3)*2
            border.color: "lightsteelblue"
            border.width: 2
            color:"lightgrey"
            radius: 3
            ListView {
                id:malzemelist
                spacing: dp(6)

                clip:true
                orientation:ListView.Vertical
               flickableDirection: Flickable.VerticalFlick
               boundsBehavior: Flickable.StopAtBounds
                anchors.fill: parent
                model:malzememodel
                delegate: malzemecomp
                focus:true

            }
        }
```

I have an model.I have fill my model When a click the button like 
model.append({mytext:"blalaladdd"}).I have set mytext to text in delage.I works but if my text is too long , wrap mode is not working.By the way I have set wrapmode:Text.Wrap.What is the problem...

mydelegate code is :

```
   Component {

        id:malzemecomp

        RowLayout
        {
            height: dp(16)
            width: parent.width
            Text {
                id: malzemeresultxt
                font.pixelSize: dp(12)
                text:malzeme
                wrapMode: Text.Wrap
                width: parent.width-dp(17)


            }
            Image {
                id: maldeleteimg
                 height: dp(16)
                 width:  dp(16)
                fillMode: Image.PreserveAspectFit
                source: "/Images/rejectmalzeme.png"
                Layout.alignment: Qt.AlignRight

                MouseArea {
                    anchors.fill: parent
                     onClicked: {
                         console.log(malzememodel.count+"/"+index);
                          TaskResult.taskresult.malzemeler.splice(index,1);
                          malzememodel.remove(index);
                          var seri=TaskResult.taskresult.serilaze();
                          console.log(seri);

                     }
                }
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: And where is your delegate code?

Comment: Ok. I have edited my post.I have added my delegate

Comment: I think the problem is using `RowLayout`. Try to add `Layout.maximumWidth` attached property to your `Text` item.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are supposed to use `Layout.xxx` properties instead of `width`/`height`/`anchors` when using `RowLayout`. Delete your `width` property from `Text` and use either `Layout.maximumWidth` with your previous width value or simply put `Layout.fillWidth: true`.

[Here is some working QML snippet](http://pastebin.com/Vw4GqAgt)